# Unable to make controller and view work together for registration form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter.

At the moment I have a register.php(VIEW) and a register.php(CONTROLLER). The register.php(VIEW) contains a simple form and from this form I am trying to pass data to the controller in order to insert it to the database. Simple.

Whenever I load the view all I seem to be getting is different error messages in relation to the variables and functions, also errors on the line which I try to load the view.

I'm simply asking:

1. Is this the correct way to be using controllers and views together?
2. How can I fix this current problem?

Below are the two files:

register.php (VIEW)

```
<htmL>

<body>

<form method="post" action="controllers/register.php">

<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="password" name="password">
<select id="userLevel" name="userLevel">        
    <option value="2">Job Seeker</option>
    <option value="3">Employer</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>

</htmL>
```

register.php (CONTROLLER)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller{  

public function __construct(){

    public $email;
    public $name;
    public $password;
    public $userLevel;

    $this->email = $_POST['email'];
    $this->name = $_POST['name'];
    $this->password = $_POST['password'];
    $this->userLevel = $_POST['userLevel'];

}

public function createuser() {

    if( filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

        $this->db->set('email', $this->email);
        $this->db->set('name', $this->name);
        $this->db->set('password', $this->password);
        $this->db->set('userLevel', $this->userLevel);
        $this->db->insert('users');

    }   

}

$this->load->view('register');

}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you defining class variables in the constructor? You might want to turn on the error reporting and see what's in the error log.

Comment: @tereško I'm sure I mentioned I was a beginner so if you could help rather asking these kind of questions.

Comment: No, I will answer the correct way now

Comment: When I check the error log it is showing the exact same errors that were displayed on the screen. Unexpected T_VARIABLE and expecting T_FUNCTION.

Comment: The answer to your error is in the above first comment.

Comment: form action should be `action="users/createuser"`

Comment: @crypticツ that's extremely vague and unhelpful, could you expand on this?

Answer (score 3):

Your controller should look like this:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{  
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function createuser() {
    if($this->input->post(null)){
        $data   = array();
        $data['email']      = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['name']       = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['password']   = $this->input->post('password');
        $data['userLevel']  = $this->input->post('userLevel');
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }
    $this->load->view('register');
}   
}
```

Instead of writing `<form method="post" action="controllers/register.php">` write `<?=form_open('user/createuser')?>`

Comment: @dianuj so I shouldn't use this method then?

Comment: Yes, right @dianuj, I have edited the code now. It should work.

Comment: @AyeTry you are using the `set` method before inserting the data which is right but when you make the array of data then you have to pass that array in the insert call

Comment: @NiloySaha +1 for you have mention the action of form

Comment: Why are database calls being done in the controller? They should be in the model.

Comment: Yes, I know, but just to make the code word I did so. @crypticツ

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this. It is MVC and more clear

VIEW

```
<htmL>

<body>

<?php echo form_open('controllers/createuser'); ?>
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="password" name="password">
<select id="userLevel" name="userLevel">        
    <option value="2">Job Seeker</option>
    <option value="3">Employer</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</body>

</htmL>
```

Controller

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Users extends CI_Controller{  

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->helper('form');

    }

    public function createuser() {

        $data['email'] = $this->input->post['email'];
        $data['name'] = $this->input->post['name'];
        $data['password'] = $this->input->post['password'];
        $data['userLevel'] = $this->input->post['userLevel'];

        if($this->input->post('submit')) {

            // Here you can validate data if you want

            $this->user_model->insert($data);
            redirect('users/success');
        }
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

    function success() {
      echo "You add user";
    }



}

    ?>
```

Model

```
class User_model extends CI_model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
    }

    function add($data) {
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);  // table name users
    }
    }
```

Comment: all this shows is page not found after I've inserted all this code into the appropriate files.

Comment: `<?php echo form_open('users/createuser'); ?>`

Comment: You need to adapt it with your code, because I dont have all your structure. I just want to show with this answer the way of MVC and how to add a simple user. So just adapt your code, check any ";" because I didnt test it, I write it on answer textarea

Comment: @dianuj it still shows 404 page not found and I'm unsure what's up with that.